# Recieving string at Views from Urls

Tags: python, django

All I want to do is pass the 'koala 2-2' string from the url to the views.  currently it returns a blank string in sitename.

```
The URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/site/koala 2-2

urls.py:
url(r'^site/(?P<sitename>)', site),

views.py
def site(request, sitename'):
    return HttpResponse('sitename: {}'.format(request))
```

Comment: You can't have an unescaped space in a URL...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `(...)` to capture what you want. In your case, use `(.+)` to capture everything.

There is also an error in your url : **It can't have space**
Then use :

```python
http://127.0.0.1:8000/site/koala-2-2
```

and capture `koala-2-2` with  :

```python
url(r'^site/(?P<sitename>(.+)', site),
```

If you want something more specific, (E.g: allow only word character and `-`, then use this one :

```
url(r'^site/(?P<sitename>([\w-]+)', site),
```

Comment: Actually, it can, it would be 'koala+2-2', and he can decode this using urllib and get the space again.

Comment: this is what I said man, space are encoded with %20 or +. Did you already see an URL with a space? Your browser replace space with `%20` then it's transparent for you but there is no real space in URL

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help guys, below is the final working solution:

```
urls.py:
url(r'^site/(?P<sitename>(.+))', site),


views.py:
def site(request, sitename):
    return HttpResponse('sitename: {}'.format(sitename))
```

It doesn't seem to care at all about a space being there, it returns the string properly either way.
I searched for an answer to this for about 3 hours before I posted, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/ has the answer there, but I missed it several times.  I sure wish they would use less complex examples.